# Windows Phone 8.1 Internet Explorer ajax timeout

Tags: ajax, windows-phone-8, timeout, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

When post ajax request from page - I get error 0 after ~60 second.
I set ajax timeout = 120 sec, but this settings not work on IE11/WindowsPhone8.1 and Microsoft Edge/Windows Mobile 10 !
How to increase default timeout on Windows Phone?

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/test1.aspx',
       type: 'post',
       timeout: 120000,
       data: {
               timestr: $('input[type=text][name=Text1]').val()
       },
       complete: function () {
                 alert('stop2');
       },
       error: function(ajaxContext) {
            alert(ajaxContext.status);
            alert(ajaxContext.statusText);
        },
       success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
       }
     });
```